# Why can't Artifactory service access mysql?

Tags: mysql, artifactory

I had Artifactory running in an AWS system, but I had to shut it down because I needed to change the instance type and increase disk space. The instance is back up and running. It's a CentOS 7 OS.

However, when I start the artifactory service, i get an exception that says "SQLException: Access denied for user 'artifactory'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

```
2017-04-19 20:11:18,111 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:207) - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDependencyDeclarationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.artifactory.api.repo.RepositoryService org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.artifacts.browse.treebrowser.tabs.general.GetDependencyDeclarationService.repositoryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.api.security.AclService org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.aclService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.storage.security.service.AclStoreService org.artifactory.security.SecurityServiceImpl.aclStoreService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.storage.db.DbService org.artifactory.storage.db.security.service.AclServiceImpl.dbService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'artifactory'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
...
2017-04-19 20:11:18,115 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:96) - Application could not be initialized: Access denied for user 'artifactory'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
```

I'm using mysql, and when I access it as root, I see the following. Is this correct?

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also see

```
mysql> select user from mysql.user;
+-------------+
| user        |
+-------------+
| artifactory |
| mysql.sys   |
| root        |
+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and have granted ALL privileges to user artifactory.

Answer (score 1):

Did you installed the MySQL on the same machine as Artifactory? If not it seems that you will need to grant the privileges to the IP of the Artifactory machine. Currently, it seems that the privilege is granted to artifactory'@**'localhost'**, not sure if this is the issue but worth checking. 
Another thing is to check the MySQL logs and see if Artifactory reached MySQL at all or if there is any proxy / firewall that is blocking Artifactory from reaching the MySQL server.

Comment: Yes, MySQL is running on the same node. However, I'm not quite sure now I indeed setup Artifactory to use it since I don't see the artdb in MySQL correct? how can I check which DB Artifactory is using?

Comment: Well Artifactory is indeed using MySQL, since I see a corresponding log in /var/log/mysql.log: 2017-04-20T13:48:07.634396Z 17 [Note] Access denied for user 'artifactory'@'localhost' (using password: YES). What file sets the uname/pw for the artifactory user?

Comment: I got it working thanks! The file I was looking for was /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/storage.properties